# How to insert a Link into a GridListTile in Gatsby

Tags: material-ui, gatsby

I am trying to have a clickable grid of images within Gatsby using the Material-UI GridList

Inside the GridListTile I am not able to put a Gatsby Link around my image or inside the GridListTileBar.

```
export default function SingleLineGridList() {

    const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <GridList className={classes.gridList} cols={1.5} cellHeight="300">
        {tileData.map(tile => (
          <GridListTile key={tile.img} className={classes.gridListTile}>
            <Link to={`product/1`}>
                <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />            
            </Link>
            <GridListTileBar
                title={tile.title}
                classes={{
                    root: classes.titleBar,
                    title: classes.title,
                }}                
                />               
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
      </GridList>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'muiName' of undefined'

I have found similar examples from straight react so presume it is something to do with the Gatsby link component

I realise it is likely to have something to do with [component wrapping](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/) but have no idea how to implement this.

How can I make the Gatsby Link element an accepted element with the GridListTile?

Comment: You have to give your component a muiName

Comment: I'm not sure how to even do that  - I am return a function not a class component - code updated to reflect that

Comment: I will write you a example today evening :)